# lost folder from /mnt and recovering

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, amazon-ec2, lost-found

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64) on Amazon AWS. 
I had a folder "foo" in the /mnt and after few modification I had to recover to previous backup of the instance .
after restore `"/mnt/foo"` folder is missing , 
however when I tried `"locate foo"` it showed me on in `"/mnt/foo"`
.

then I did `updatedb` command and then `/mnt/foo` no longer visible in the `locate foo` command.

`/mnt` only have `lost+found` directory .

`df` command give following.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8115168 6991056    688836  92% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             3824796      12   3824784   1% /dev
tmpfs             765952     352    765600   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3829752       0   3829752   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       30824956   45140  29207336   1% /mnt
```

and `sudo fdisk -l` gives following .

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *       16065    16771859     8377897+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/xvdb: 32.2 GB, 32204390400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3915 cylinders, total 62899200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

edit 1 :

`fsck` shows ,

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/xvdb is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

What can be happened to the directory "foo" in the /mnt and is there  any possibility that I can get it back ?

Comment: The output of `locate` is cached. The fact that `/mnt/foo` showed up with `locate` does not mean it's actually there.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto yes , I did a  : updatedb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably mounted the partition `/dev/xvdb`over the original `/mnt` ? Try

```
umount /dev/xvdb
```

an see, if the folder is there. If so, move it to some other partition, then re-mount `/dev/xvdb` and move the folder back.

Comment: output for `umount /dev/xvdb` 
`umount: /mnt: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))`

Comment: I tried `umount -l /dev/xvdb' and now `lost+found` dir from /mnt also gone.

Comment: Then the folder has been deleted somehow. What were your original steps for the restore process ?

Comment: amazon ec2 , backup image and restore procedure .

Comment: since I still have the backup image , will there any possibility to get it back ? with new restore instance ?

Comment: If the folder is backed up within the image, surely

Answer (score 1):

You can create `/mnt/foo` mount point and mount `/dev/xvdb` using following commands.

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo mkdir /mnt/foo
sudo mount /dev/xvdb /mnt/foo
```

If you are getting device busy,find process running with device and kill it

```
lsof | grep '/dev/xvdb'
```

Comment: I've followed these steps and in the `/mnt/foo` directory it only have `lost+found` , I did `cd lost+found` and `ll` only shows `.swp` file in it . 
seems I lost the directory ?

Comment: it looks like it might have been formatted.

Comment: `cd /dev/xvdb` gives  `-bash: cd: /dev/xvdb: Not a directory` output .